# Best approach for using AJAX loaders?

Tags: ajax, loader

I've implemented a few poor solutions for bringing up an AJAX loader before dynamically updating a content DIV, but none seem to be "universal", and I find each time I do it I'm reworking it. If I have a DIV with content that updates depending on what a user clicks on the page, and I want to display the loader over this content DIV, what is the best approach? I've seen some developers have the loader always on the page, and they just display it block or none, and I've seen others append it to the DIV. What about when you also have multiple areas that can update? I'm thinking something repeatable that I can call with a function, maybe passing a few parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some JavaScript libraries allow listening to opening and closing requests. Check out Prototype's request Responder http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/responders.

You would do something like this:

```
Ajax.Responders.register({
  onCreate: function() {
    $('loader').show();
    Ajax.activeRequestCount++;
  },
  onComplete: function() {
    Ajax.activeRequestCount--;
    if (Ajax.activeRequestCount < 1) $('loader').hide();
  }
});
```

As for visual representation of loading, you may want to identify the different parts of your page which may require separate loading graphics and subclass the Request object, each time indicating the type of request.

E.g.
Is it a field being saved? `new FieldUpdateRequest(field)`
Is it the page being loaded? `new Request();`
Is a container being updated? `new PartialRequest(div);`

Then capture each subclasses type and show or hide a different loader graphic.

There is unfortunately no quick solution, hal. You could build a generic script for appending loader graphics to containers, that should save you some repetition. If you do, mind posting it here :)?

Comment: This was a great answer. Thanks for providing all the detail.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [JQuery progress bar](http://ui.jquery.com/repository/latest/demos/functional/#ui.progressbar) or something similar in a different library.